# Is there a way to programmatically scroll to a PDF page within a Ipad Safari?

Tags: html, ipad, safari

I'm current trying to display a pdf inside an iframe

`<iframe id="iFrame" height="583px" width="785px" src="pdf/test.pdf" scrolling="yes" ></iframe>`

after i test on ipad, i found out that it cannot be scroll. is there any solution to this? 
Thanks.

Comment: load the pdf outside the iframe, gives the user more flexibility

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest using [Scribd's](http://www.scribd.com/) service, it even let's you restrict user downloads if that is a concern.

Answer (score 0):

If you place two fingers on the text in the pdf, you can scroll that text instead of the whole page.